# How to return a value of indeterminate type from a switch statement from a method

Tags: c#, switch-statement, return, return-value

I have the following switch statement:

```
switch (SomeType)
{
    case SomeType.A:
        var data = (Type_1)SomeType.Data;
    case SomeType.B:
        var data = (Type_2)SomeType.Data;
    case SomeType.C:
        var data = (Type_3) SomeType.Data;
    case SomeType.D:
        var data = (Type_4) SomeType.Data;
    case SomeType.E:
        var data = (Type_5) SomeType.Data;
    case SomeType.F:
        var data = (Type_6) SomeType.Data;
}
```

I have two problems with this:

One being the switch statement seems to treat the whole thing as one scope, therefore I can't set `var data` multiple times, I think I can overcome this because this needs to be wrapped in a method that returns the value, so I can just do something like `return (Type_6) SomeType.Data;`.

The second problem is how can I wrap this in a return method? As far as I know in C# the method must explicitly define the return type. Any ideas?

Comment: What is SomeType?  Does it share a common interface?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? So far it sounds like a bad architectural decision.

Comment: Do your types have a common base class or interface they derive from?

Comment: @DavidL `SomeType` would be a parameter passed into the function

Comment: @walther I want to encapsulate this switch into a function and return the casted type, (`var data`) since the cast is never the same, I don't know how to write the return type of the function.

Comment: @user4612487 I think you misunderstood my question.  You're casting to various types which seems suspicious.  Why?  What is the Type_1 etc. relationship to SomeData?

Comment: Either I am completely misunderstanding the question or this question completely ignores the fact that C# is a strongly typed language. I suggest looking at the problem from a different angle because I'm 99% sure that you are taking the wrong approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Dynamic

You can use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) as a return type:

```
public dynamic GetData()
{
    dynamic data;
    switch (SomeType)
    {
        case SomeType.A:
            data = (Type_1)SomeType.Data;
        case SomeType.B:
            data = (Type_2)SomeType.Data;
        case SomeType.C:
            data = (Type_3) SomeType.Data;
        case SomeType.D:
            data = (Type_4) SomeType.Data;
        case SomeType.E:
            data = (Type_5) SomeType.Data;
        case SomeType.F:
            data = (Type_6) SomeType.Data;
        default: throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Just add some `break` statements or it won't compile.

But dynamic is [highly contagious](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/11/05/dynamic-contagion-part-one.aspx) - if you use it in one method it will probably propagate through all methods that use the original method.

---

#### Reworking architecture

While dynamic is a quick fix, it is not the best solution, as it has been already pointed by commentators. Ideally, you should strive to preserve type information as much as possible - it simplifies development and reduces the likelihood of mistakes.

You can use some base class or interface for all your possible data objects:

```
    public interface IData
    {
        // Common properties and methods
    }

    public IData GetData()
    {
        return SomeData.Data;
    }
```

But it may require a substantial reconsideration of your architecture, that may or may not be possible if different `Data` types differ too much.

#### Visitor Pattern

If it is the case, then you may take a look at [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) that deals with cases when you data has to be processed very differently. It still requires the same base interface as return type, but now it will look like:

```
public interface IData
{
    void Accept(IDataVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IDataVisitor
{
    void Visit(DataA data);
    void Visit(DataB data);
    void Visit(DataC data);
}

public class DataA : IData { public void Accept(IDataVisitor visitor) {visitor.Visit(this);}}
public class DataB : IData { public void Accept(IDataVisitor visitor) {visitor.Visit(this);}}
public class DataC :  IData { public void Accept(IDataVisitor visitor) {visitor.Visit(this);}}

public class ConsoleVisitor : IDataVisitor
{
    public void Visit(DataA data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A" + data);
    }

    public void Visit(DataB data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B" + data);
    }

    public void Visit(DataC data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C" + (data);
    }
}
```